# Searchbar cause input unchecked

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a `ul` that displays users with a checkbox `input`. When searching for a user by surname/first name, the previously selected `input` checkboxes are removed. How to prevent it?

```
function App() {
let copyList = useRef();
const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  fetch(api)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      copyList.current = data;
      setContacts(copyList.current);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}, []);

contacts.sort((a, b) => (a.last_name > b.last_name ? 1 : -1));

const searchHandler = (value) => {
  const contactsList = [...copyList.current].filter((x) => {
    if (value.toLowerCase().includes(x.last_name.toLowerCase())) {
      return x.last_name.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase());
    } else if (value.toLowerCase().includes(x.first_name.toLowerCase())) {
      return x.first_name.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase());
    } else if (value === "") {
      return x;
    }
  });
  setContacts(contactsList);
};

return (
  <div className="App">
    <Header />
    <SearchBar onSearch={(value) => searchHandler(value)} />
    <ContactsList contacts={contacts} />
  </div>
);
}
```

Input component is in ContactsList component.

```
function Input(props) {
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false);
  const [id] = useState(props.id);

  const handleChange = () => {
    setIsChecked(!isChecked);
    console.log(id);
  };

  return (
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      className={style.contact_input}
      checked={isChecked}
      onChange={handleChange}
      value={id}
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you filter the contacts and update the `contacts` state, the list in `ContactList` will be re-rendered as it is a new array which means you will have a new set of `Input` components with the default state. In order to persist the previously selected items you will also have to store the array of selected IDs in state. The `Input` component should receive the `isChecked` and `onChange` values from props so you can pass in a condition where you check if the current ID is in the list of selected IDs which means it is checked and when the user clicks on it, you can just simply update that array by adding the ID if it's not currently in the array or removing from it if it is already present (copying the array first since it's a state variable).